# Intersection of 2 sets

Tags: c++, function, intersection

I wrote a function in C++ for finding an intersection and union of 2 sets.

I tried this following function:

intersection function:

```
bool member (int x[10],int s[10])
{
    bool result=false;

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        for (int j=0 ; j<10;j++)
             if (x[i]==s[j])
                 result=true;


    return result;
}
int intersection(int s1[10],int s2[10],int s3[10])
{
    for ( int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++)

    {

        if (member(s1,s2)==true)
            s3[i]=s1[i];
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific than "It doesn't work." Also, what did you discover when you used a debugger?

Comment: for example when i give first array(s1) values of {1,3,7,9} (i give other elements -1) and the second array (s2) values of {1,3,4,6,9} it gives me {1,3,7,9}(exactly the first array)

Comment: Great! Step through the code in a debugger. Is the problem in the `member` function, where it is giving the wrong answer? Or is it in the way the `intersection` function  builds the result?

Comment: i use intersection function for the result i mean in main function i used intersection(s1,s2,s3) then i cout s3!!!  i hope i understand your question :))!

Comment: Why? You could just use `std::set_intersection` - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection - there's also `std::set_union` - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union

Comment: i am learning c++ for near 3 months and i am not very professional in coding! i need to write a function like what i used in my question. please help!!!!!

Comment: First, you have to sort the two arrays. Then, to check if an element is in both sets, you will need two indexes: one in the first array, one in the second one. If the elements are equal, add one to output. If not, advance the index of the smaller one.

Answer (score 1):

You can try union and intersection of two sets of user input size as below :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
void main()
{
    int *a, *b, *c, *d, n1, n2, i, j, k=0, l=0, flag=0;
    printf("Enter number of elements in A and B : ");
    scanf("%d %d",&n1,&n2);
    a = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*n1);
    b = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*n2);
    c = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*((n1>n2)?n1:n2));
    d = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*(n1+n2));

    printf("\nEnter element in set A : ");
    for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter element : ");
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    printf("\nEnter elements in set B : ");
    for(i=0;i<n2;i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter element : ");
        scanf("%d",&b[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n2;j++)
        {
            if(a[i]==b[j])
            {
                c[l++]=a[i];
                j=0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<n2;i++)
        d[k++]=a[i];
    for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
    {
        flag=0;
        for(j=0;j<n2;j++)
                                                                                                               {
            if(b[i]==a[j])
            {
                flag=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!flag)
            d[k++]=b[i];
    }
    printf("\n\t A = {");
    for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
    {
        printf("%d",a[i]);
    }
    printf("}");
    printf("\n\t B = {");
    for(i=0;i<n2;i++)
    {
        printf("%d",b[i]);
    }
    printf("}");
    printf("\n\t A U B = {");
    for(i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
        printf("%d",d[i]);
    }
    printf("}");
    printf("\n\t A n B = {");
    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        printf("%d",c[i]);
    }
    printf("}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're copying `s1` in `s3`, one item at a time, if `member(s1, s2)` return `true`, that is if it's an intersection between `s1` and `s2`

You should rewrite in this way (caution: not tested)

```
bool member (int x, int s[10])
{
    bool result=false;

    for (int j=0 ; (! result) && (j<10);j++)
         if (x==s[j])
             result=true;

    return result;
}

int intersection(int s1[10],int s2[10],int s3[10])
{
    int j = -1;

    for ( int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++)
    {
        if (member(s1[i],s2)==true)
            s3[++j]=s1[i];
    }

  // what about other places of s3?

  return 0;
}
```